# Documentation window takes focus from the editor

Tags: android-studio

It's kind of tricky to explain but let me try.

> Say I want to type `Log.wtf` with the `Documentation` window (`View` →
>   `Quick Documentation`) open whether floating or docked, it gets
>   focused as soon as I finish typing `Lo` (doesn't necessarily have to
>   be 2 keystrokes). After a sigh, I click on the last character and try to
>   add `g`, but the editor has already lost her focus again.

It happens ***sometimes*** and only when the `Documentation` window is active. For the rest of the time, the code completion shows first as expected and then the documentation window gets updated without a focus robbery.

Am I the only one suffering from this?

Comment: happen to me too when the android studio emulator is running.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

- Place the cursor on an any meaningful token such as a variable, class, etc.
- Hit `[View] → [Quick Documentation]` (`Ctrl + Q` for me) "several times".

You might see it start to work... which pretty much smells like a bug. :s

Comment: This work for me after hiding Documentation windows twice- i think. Now it's back to normal state. This is irritating. Thanks you @Suzi